# Which proxy sites can I use for git?

Tags: git, proxy

I want to configure my git with a proxy from the command below. Unfortunately, the proxies I have tried are not working. Can anyone suggest any free proxies tested on git.Because of this, I am not able to clone or push to any repository.

```
git config --global http.proxy http://proxyuser:proxypwd@proxy.server.com:8080
```

Comment: Please note that [questions asking for the recommendation of off-site resources are off-topic for Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251134/2747593). Instead, if you have a specific question about code that *you have written*, please show us [what you have tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com), and be sure to include a [mcve]. See also [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear:

- a Git http.proxy config does override the HTTP proxy, normally configured using the `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `all_proxy` environment variables
  So even if you clone an *https* Git repo, that `http.proxy` setting will be used.
- the `proxyuser:proxypwd` are *not* your Git credentials, but the ones needed to authenticate on the proxy.
- it is possible to specify a proxy string with a user name but no password, in which case git will attempt to acquire one in the same way it does for other credentials.
  For instance, [Git for Windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) can be linked to the Windows Credential Store with the Git Credential Manager for Windows: you can cache your proxy password as well as your Git accounts passwords there.
  (`git config --global credential.helper manager`)

So you are doing it right, but need to say more about "not working": a proxy is only needed if direct internet access is blocked (typically at work)
At least set `GIT_TRACE_PACKET` to `true`, to enable packet-level tracing for network operations.

As the [OP Shubham Nagaria](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5127742/shubham-nagaria) [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41272686/which-proxy-sites-can-i-use-for-git#comment69748014_41272856), proxy was not needed:

> Actually I was just unsetting the global http and https whereas my system http was set to something...once I unset it, it worked smoothly.

Comment: when i try to git clone, it gives me "Could not resolve proxy: proxy_addr" error..so what should I do to resolve this?

Comment: @ShubhamNagaria why do you need a proxy in the first place? Does a direct internet access not possible?

Comment: @ShubhamNagaria "Could not resolve" means your network DNS does not know how to translate proxy_addr into an IP. Try using the IP of the proxy directly.

Comment: Yes, but i do not want to use proxy..it's not a work network. there shouldn't be any restrictions,right?

Comment: @ShubhamNagaria yes, if you can browse internet (and if your browser is not configured to use proxy), Git should not need to set any proxy either.

Comment: Even if I unset http.proxy and https.proxy, I still get could not resolve proxy_addr.

Comment: @ShubhamNagaria unsetting those git configs means Git should not try to resolve any proxy url. Do you have any environment variables named htt_proxy or https_proxy?

Comment: Ok got it! Actually I was just unsetting the global http and https whereas my system http was set to something...once I unset it, it worked smoothly. Thanks again :)

Comment: @ShubhamNagariaa Great. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility: you can read http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer and http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You should, under no circumstances, push to a http git repo without https, **especially when going through a proxy**.

There's no telling what the operators of that proxy do with your git credentials.

So, **please don't do this**. I don't know why this doesn't work for you, but generally, proxy servers, especially free ones, are probably not really fans of people doing very complicated stuff over HTTP, like cloning git repos.

As usual, you might want to use Tor instead.